# How to read text file by block with Java 8 streams

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, nio2

I want to read an ASCII file that is composed of "blocks" that are delimited by start and end tags.

I have never used Java 8 streams and I would like to test them on this file reader, but I don't really know how to do it.

For the sake of simplicity, let's consider the following file format (actual file format [can be found here](http://geuz.org/gmsh/doc/texinfo/gmsh.html#MSH-ASCII-file-format)):

```
$Node
6
1 1.0 0.0 0.0
2 -1.0 0.0 0.0
3 0.0 1.0 0.0
4 0.0 -1.0 0.0
5 0.0 0.0 1.0
6 0.0 0.0 -1.0
$EndNode
$Elements
3
1 10 1 2 3
2 10 4 5 6
3 10 1 5 3
$EndElements
```

Where the first line of each block is the number of elements in the block. Then each block is a list of space-separated values. Number of values and types vary depending on the block.

In real life, the file can get pretty big (several hundred Mb, maybe up to a few Gb), so performance is critical.

Using Java NIO 2 (without the Java 8 streams), I would have done something like this:

```
BufferedReader reader = Files.newBufferedReader(filePath, Charset.defaultCharset());
String line = null;
Parser currentParser = defaultParser;
while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
    if (line.startsWith("$")) {
        currentParser = getParser(line);
        continue;
    }
    currentParser.parseLine(line);
}
```

With a line parser that would be smart enough to deal with the first line of the block differently that the rest (without having to test a isFirstLineOfBlock boolean for each line)... Don't know yet how to do that either by the way.

Anyway, I would appreciate some help with using Java 8 streams for this file reader.

Final question, what is the advantage of using Java streams for such an application: is it just a question of readability or can I expect improved performances?

Comment: Well Streams are not really suited for this. Your for-loop code looks just fine.

Comment: That's too bad... I thus coded the Java 7 way...

Comment: Same exact question came up for me. Seems like there should be a way to get a Stream of partitioned Streams. So you could have partitions = lines.partitionBy( line -> line.startsWith("$") ).  Then you could walk  partition.forEachOrdered()  line by line.

Answer (score 1):

You have several ways to do it with Java 8 streams. For example,

```
try (BufferedReader br = Files.newBufferedReader(Paths.get(filePath, Charset.defaultCharset())) {
    br.lines()
        .filter(line -> !line.startsWith("$"))
        .forEachOrdered(currentParser::parseLine);
} catch (IOException ex) {
    throw new Error(ex);
}
```

[.lines()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#lines--) method description contains

```
The Stream is lazily populated, i.e., 
read only occurs during the terminal stream operation.
```

In this example terminal operation is `forEachOrdered`

---

another one

```
try (Stream<String> stream = Files.lines(Paths.get(filePath, Charset.defaultCharset())) {
    stream
        .filter(line -> !line.startsWith("$"))
        .forEachOrdered(currentParser::parseLine);
} catch (IOException ex) {
    throw new Error(ex);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to parse such constructs with the help of my free [StreamEx](https://github.com/amaembo/streamex) library which enhances standard Stream API:

```
StreamEx.ofLines(filePath, Charset.defaultCharset())
        .groupRuns((a, b) -> !b.startsWith("$"))
        .forEachOrdered(list -> 
            list.subList(1, list.size()).forEach(getParser(list.get(0))::parseLine));
```

Here we use [`groupRuns`](http://amaembo.github.io/streamex/javadoc/one/util/streamex/StreamEx.html#groupRuns-java.util.function.BiPredicate-) method which combines single file entry into the list. The argument passed to `groupRuns` is the `BiPredicate` which applies to the pair of adjacent input elements which should return true if the elements must be grouped. Here we group elements unless the next one starts with `"$"`. After that we have lazily populated `Stream<List<String>>` and parse each group creating the parser using the first line and calling `parseLine` for all subsequent lines.